# tex4ebook: How to get colored text in tables

Tags: tabularx, tex4ht, tex4ebook

Extending the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686353/tex4ebook-how-to-get-colored-text-in-enumerations), is there also a way to get a colored text in a `tabularx` environment?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{colorenv}[1]{\color{#1}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{colorenv}{blue}
This text is blue.

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X |}
\hline
This text is black & although I would like to have it blue.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{colorenv}

\end{document}
```

And here the config-file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewenvironment{colorenv}[1]{
\get:xcolorcss{#1}\:colorenv
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div~style="color:\:colorenv">}\par\ShowPar
}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: The color in table is displayed correctly in web browser, but not in Calibre's `ebook-viewer`. It is possible that it is a Calibre's issue.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks, you are right, in web browser the text is indeed colored. However, I just saw that the vertical and horizontal lines are black even in the web browser, while they are also colored when compiling a pdf. Is there a way to get them colored as well?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. One is that Calibre doesn't show text in the right color, the other is related to table rules colors, which is set to black by TeX4ht.

The first issue can be fixed with this CSS declaration:

```
\Css{table{color: inherit;}}
```

It just tells Calibre to use the parent element's color for table. It seems that it sets it to black by default.

The fix for rules is more complicated. I had to copy some configurations that sets rule colors and change the explicit color to use the `\:colorenv` color. This is the full config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\def\:colorenv{black}
\renewenvironment{colorenv}[1]{
\get:xcolorcss{#1}\:colorenv
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div style="color:\:colorenv" class="colorenv">}\par\ShowPar
}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}

\Configure{VBorder}
   {\let\VBorder\empty \let\AllColMargins\empty
    \global\let\GROUPS\empty \HAssign\NewGroup = 0
    \gHAdvance\Next:TableNo by 1 \global\let\TableNo=\Next:TableNo }
   {\xdef\VBorder{\VBorder\ifnum \NewGroup> 0 </colgroup>\fi}
    \HAssign\NewGroup = 0 % \gdef\GROUPS{rules="groups"}}
    % put vertical border for a column
    \ifnum\ar:cnt > 0%
      % in all other cases, we should put right border
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt {border-right:1px solid \:colorenv;}}%
    \else%
      % columns are numbered from 1. if \ar:cnt == 0 then it is the left border
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-1{border-left: 1px solid \:colorenv;}}%
    \fi%
   }
   {\Advance:\NewGroup by 1
    \ifnum \NewGroup=1 \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder<colgroup
        id="TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt g">}\fi
    \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder<col\Hnewline id="TBL-\TableNo
       -\ar:cnt"\xml:empty>}\xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins1}}
   {\xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins 0}}
\AddToHook{env/tabularx/after}{
\Css{.colorenv \#TBL-\TableNo\space .hline{border-top: 1px solid \:colorenv;}}
}
\catcode`\:=12
\Css{table{color: inherit;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And this is the result:

[image]